# How to install 'warnings' package in Python?

Tags: python, package

I've seen Python programs using

```
import warnings
```

How to install that package? I tried

```
pip install --upgrade warnings
```

and got an error

```
Collecting warnings
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement warnings (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for warnings
```

Comment: ... https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`warnings` is builtin. No need to install it.

Comment: That's the answer I need. Not the other with a link to a big page without pointing out how it's relevant and a downvote.

Answer (score 1):

pip install pytest-warnings

Use this command for warnings installation